# The word covered by SpannableStringBuilder in a string gets invisible. How to fix it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, toast, android-toast

Here's a sample of the code:

```
String engText = "The story of Sir Walter Raleigh";
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

textView3.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView3.setText(addClickablePart(engText), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

where

```
private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str)
{
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);
    ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget)
            {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"tale",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }, 4, 9, 0);

    return ssb;
}
```

In this code, when you tap on the word *story*, a toast pops up saying *tale*. But **here's the problem:** In Android of versions 4 and higher, the word *story* gets invisible, while still you can tap on the blank (invisible) space and the toast pops up without trouble.

**How can I keep the word "*story*" visible or change its color so it stays visible while it will work as a toast when tapped?**

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it myself;

after the first *setSpan*, I needed to begin immediately with another *setSpan* which changes the color of the same word. Here it is:

```
ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 4, 9,
   Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```